# Docker ADD не удаётся найти папку после сбора контейнера

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker

Есть простой Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest 

ADD app.py / \

COPY /files /files/ 

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev libexpat1-dev gettext \
    libz-dev libssl-dev git curl wget python3-tk \
    && cd /usr/local/bin \
    && ln -s /usr/bin/python3 python \
    && pip3 install --upgrade pip

RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir \
    'sanic' 

CMD [ "python3", "./app.py" ]
```

Такой app.py

app = Sanic()
app.static('/files', './files')

```
@app.route("/")
@app.route("/index")
def index(request):
    response = file(join(dirname(__file__),'/files/index.html'))
    return response
```

И такая структура:

**ИСПРАВИЛ СТРУКТУРУ**

```
/files [folder]
/app.py [file]
/Dockerfile [file]
```

Но почему-то пытаясь зайти на `/` или `/index`, я получаю ошибку: `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/files/index.html'`

Как посмотреть структуру файловую контейнера ?

Как понять причину, по которой приложение не видит папку ?

Заранее спасибо за любую помощь.

Answer (score 1):

> Как посмотреть структуру файловую контейнера ?

В самом простом случае (без изменений entrypoint)

```
docker run --rm -ti <image> bash
```

Это запустит новый контейнер и баш внутри него. Часто требуется подключиться к уже запущенному контейнеру:

```
docker exec -ti <container> bash
```

> Как понять причину, по которой приложение не видит папку ?

Посмотреть в лог:

```
Step 2/2 : ADD app.py / COPY /files /files/
```

У вас используется обратный слэш сразу за директивой ADD:

```
ADD app.py / \

COPY /files /files/
```

Это равнозначно следующей записи:

```
ADD app.py / COPY /files /files/
```

У меня в этот момент демон отказался собирать образ, потому что отсутствует файл COPY, у вас, очевидно, по какой-то причине процесс прошел дальше

---

В то же время, если правильно интепретирую структуру:

```
/files
  /app.py
  /Dockerfile
  /index.html
```

То COPY не добавит вам ничего, потому что передаваемый контекст - это и есть сама директория files, и `COPY /files /files` на самом деле попытается скопировать `files/files`

Comment: Исправил структуру.
За ответ спасибо больщое.